# How to update multiple values in JSONB array Postgresql array object

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, sql-update, jsonb

I have a JSONB array below

```
[
  {"name":"test","age":"21","phone":"6589","town":"54"},
  {"name":"test12","age":"67","phone":"6546","town":"54"}
]
```

Now I want to update `town`,`phone`,`age` if `name` is **test**.
How to update multiple values in JSONB array?

Comment: This would be so easy with a properly normalized data model.

Comment: Are you sure you want to store it like that? You might run in to issues later on. Even though a bit old, I would suggest you read this post on why it might be a bad idea. [PostgreSQL anti-patterns: Unnecessary json/hstore dynamic columns](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/postgresql-anti-patterns-unnecessary-jsonhstore-dynamic-columns/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query is longer, but it should clarify expanding the original column to make the replacements:

```
with injson as (
  select '[
  {"name":"test","age":"21","phone":"6589","town":"54"},
  {"name":"test12","age":"67","phone":"6546","town":"54"}
]'::jsonb as jarray
), substitution as (
  select '{"name": "test", "age": "22", "phone": "6590", "town": "55"}'::jsonb as jnew
), expand as (
  select jsonb_array_elements(jarray) as jold
    from injson
), cond_update as (
  select coalesce(s.jnew, e.jold) as element
    from expand e
         left join substitution s
                on s.jnew->>'name' = e.jold->>'name'
)
select jsonb_agg(element) as result
  from cond_update;
                                                             result                                                             
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [{"age": "22", "name": "test", "town": "55", "phone": "6590"}, {"age": "67", "name": "test12", "town": "54", "phone": "6546"}]
(1 row)
```

Based on the description of your table, it should look something like this:

```
with substitution as (
  select '{"name": "test", "age": "22", "phone": "6590", "town": "55"}'::jsonb as jnew
), expand as (
  select id, jsonb_array_elements("caloriesConsumption") as jold
    from "calorieTracker"
   where id = 1
), cond_update as (
  select id, coalesce(s.jnew, e.jold) as element
    from expand e
         left join substitution s
                on s.jnew->>'name' = e.jold->>'name'
)
update "calorieTracker" 
   set "caloriesConsumption" = cu.element
  from cond_update
 where cond_update.id = "calorieTracker".id;
```

Comment: @AvinashJagtap  If you want to see the `update`, then add your table information to your question.

Comment: [
  {"name":"test","age":"21","phone":"6589","town":"54"},
  {"name":"test12","age":"67","phone":"6546","town":"54"}
]

Comment: @AvinashJagtap  That is not a table.  That is only a JSON array.  What is your database table name, and what columns are in it?

Comment: table name: calorieTracker and two column id and caloriesConsumption. this is my table infor in te table i have two columns id  is int   and caloriesConsumption  is haveing jsob data type. What i am looking for i want to update id 1 and if c_date is forex:"08/08/2020" i want to update that object. I hope i have provided exat information.

Comment: @AvinashJagtap  I added an example update statement to my answer.

Comment: I tried the above solution but it is removing another object in array and update new values. {"c_id": 15, "date": "10/08/2020", "c_tag": "16", "c_fats": "0.2", "c_item": "update test"} it should replace with existing one

Answer (score 2):

You can update them dynamically by indexing each individual element :

For **age** :

```
WITH s AS
(
 SELECT ('{'||idx-1||',age}')::text[] AS path
   FROM tab 
  CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(jsdata) 
   WITH ORDINALITY arr(j,idx)
  WHERE j->>'name'='test' 
)
UPDATE tab
   SET jsdata = jsonb_set(jsdata,s.path,'"15"',false)
  FROM s
```

For **town** :

```
WITH s AS
(
 SELECT ('{'||idx-1||',town}')::text[] AS path
   FROM tab 
  CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(jsdata) 
   WITH ORDINALITY arr(j,idx)
  WHERE j->>'name'='test' 
)
UPDATE tab
   SET jsdata = jsonb_set(jsdata,s.path,'"55"',false)
  FROM s
```

For **phone** :

```
WITH s AS
(
 SELECT ('{'||idx-1||',phone}')::text[] AS path
   FROM tab 
  CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(jsdata) 
   WITH ORDINALITY arr(j,idx)
  WHERE j->>'name'='test' 
)
UPDATE tab
   SET jsdata = jsonb_set(jsdata,s.path,'"1111"',false)
  FROM s
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=54e95eccb0513adc59f9e6dae4725d90)</kbd>

Or **directly at a time** :

```
WITH s AS
(
 SELECT ('{'||idx-1||',phone}')::text[] AS path_phone,
        ('{'||idx-1||',town}')::text[] AS path_town,
        ('{'||idx-1||',age}')::text[] AS path_age
   FROM tab 
  CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(jsdata) 
   WITH ORDINALITY arr(j,idx)
  WHERE j->>'name'='test' 
)
UPDATE tab
   SET jsdata = jsonb_set(jsonb_set(jsonb_set(jsdata,
                                              s.path_phone,
                                              '"1111"',
                                              false),
                                    path_town,
                                    '"55"',
                                    false),
                          s.path_age,
                          '"20"',
                          false)
      FROM s
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5ca59a9a5ebb8b2d9f0e3f873102eaf5)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. can I update it in one query using jsonb_set? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=d05884cee200ed3516266c6113c68d7d I have found it this but here we can update menu_name only but in my case, i want to one or more value in object.

Comment: you're welcome @AvinashJagtap , I also added the case performing at a time.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try this one. saved my day.

Comment: I have added another object in JSON trying to update. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c9a1af68ace769f8c50339cb8845f016 instead of changing can we replace the whole object with an existing one?

Answer (score 1):

Below query will give you results which contains `test` word in them. After you find these you can update any values in other columns.

[Working Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6TMkM4MsPx3v5xS6CFtzwu/0)

```
 CREATE TABLE TEST2 (
    INFO JSON NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO TEST2 (info)
VALUES('[
  {"name":"test","age":"21","phone":"6589","town":"54"},
  {"name":"test12","age":"67","phone":"6546","town":"54"},
  {"name":"dest147","age":"67","phone":"6546","town":"54"}
]');

SELECT *
FROM TEST2,
json_array_elements(info) elem
WHERE elem ->> 'name' like '%test%';
```